# Java polymorphism casting - runtime error ClassCastException

Tags: java, casting, polymorphism

I have this code here:

```
public class code {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Animal ani1 = new Animal();
        Animal ani2 = new Dog();

        Dog d1 = (Dog)ani1; //runtime error ClassCastException
        Dog d2 = (Dog)ani2;
    }
}

class Animal {
    public String name = "animal";
    public void talk(){
        System.out.println("Animal");
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    public String name = "dog";
    public void talk(){
        System.out.println("Dog");
    }
}
```

I am not understanding why a runtime error is occurring and downcasting in general. There are 2 objects being created, an `Animal` object and a `Dog` object. Each is referenced to by a variable of type `Animal`.

I think Java will not assign `d1` an object of type `Animal` because `d1` was declared as type `Dog`. But what is confusing me is that both `ani1` and `ani2` are type `Animal`, and should be able to be downcasted to `Dog` right? The only difference is that one is referencing an `Animal` object and the other a `Dog` object.

Does Java know that `ani1` is referencing an `Animal` object and will not allow `d1` to be assigned a variable that references an `Animal` object?

Comment: If you write `Object x = new Object();`, can you cast `x` to a String?  No, you can’t, because it’s not a String.  Casting does not change what something *is;*  it only changes how your code recognizes it.  If your object wasn’t already a Dog instance, casting it will not change it into a Dog instance.  How you choose to refer to your objects does not determine what they actually are.

Comment: ...and since you asked, Java knows an object's internal type despite what the variable is declared as.  That's why the `instanceof` operator works.  `ani2 instanceof Dog` will return true despite `ani2` being declared as `Animal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [comment by VGR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471208/java-polymorphism-casting-runtime-error-classcastexception#comment89910763_51471208) is correct, but let me elaborate for your specific situation. A Dog is an Animal, but an Animal is not necessarily a Dog. You could create `Dog` objects and pass them around as `Animal` objects, but not the other way around. A common way to handle this would be the following:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {        
    Dog dog = new Dog();
    makeMeTalk(dog);
}

public static void makeMeTalk(Animal animal) {
    animal.talk();
}
```

The output of this would be: `Dog`.

Answer (score 2):

What VGR said was right, you cannot change what something is. Casting is only here to help our code during compilation recognize what it is.

Consider the ff example:

```
Animal ani1 = new Cat();
Animal ani2 = new Dog();

Dog dog1 = (Dog) ani1; // will produce a runtime error
Dog dog2 = (Dog) ani2;
```

Just like the given example, you cannot simple change `Cat` to `Dog` by simply casting. `Dog` will always be an `Animal` but an `Animal` can't always be a `Dog`.